# How can I differentiate between a click on a pager item and a click on a prev/next item in Cycle2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle2

I'm using Mike Alsup's awesome Cycle2 jquery plugin on a slideshow that features both a custom pager element (thumbnails) and previous/next buttons.  How can I trigger an action using the cycle-after event *only* if the pager was clicked.

```
$('#myslideshow').on('cycle-after',function(e, optionHash, outgoingSlideEl, incomingSlideEl, forwardFlag){
    // Do something here only if the pager was clicked.
});
```

I don't want to use the click event from the pager element - that won't wait until the slide transition is complete, it fires right away, and seems to conflict with the slideshow animations sometimes.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for the same and describe your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about setting a boolean value to true during the click event of your pager item or the `cycle-pager-activated` event, and using that value inside the `cycle-after` event, then reset it back to false.

Comment: long delay… I had moved on to another solution pretty quickly last Feb.  This looks like a great approach.